# Access media file info

Tags: php, file, media, extract

I have a large number of media files, .wmv , which I would like to extract information from; filename, size, date created, comments and tags etc.

I have a small snippet of php code which allows me to access the basic info like the name, size and date created, but I cannot find a way to access the more detailed info like comments, ratings and tags.

```
<?php  
$imgdir = 'images/';

$strFileName = "meg4_big.wmv";  
$objFopen = fopen($strFileName,"r");  
echo "Files Size = ".filesize($strFileName) . "<br>";  
echo "Read able = ".is_readable($strFileName) . "<br>";  
echo "Write able = ".is_writable($strFileName) . "<br>";  
echo "Modify Date = ".date( "D d M Y g:i A", filemtime($strFileName)) . "<br>";  
echo "Last Updated Time = ".date( "D d M Y g:i A", filemtime($strFileName)) . "<br>"; 
fclose ($objFopen);

?>
```

Does anyone know of any way to access this extra information? It doesnt need to be php, but it would be prefereable.

Comment: You are looking for `meta` info on the file, which is accessed through a different function. `fopen` can tell you the basics about the file, not the content.

Comment: You don't need to fopen() the file for any of the operations in your code snippet. But you will once you start reading the 'real' metadata (e.g. comments).

Comment: I would say ffmpeg-php is a way to go. You can extract lots of metadata out of your video.

Comment: I also might suggest that you look at the PHP SplFileInfo, DreictroyIterator, adn REcursiveDirectoryIterator classes.  If you are going to be needing to access basic file information frequently across a large number of files in a directory (or nested directories) these can really simplify things for you.  Though this won't help with mpeg metadata

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I wont need to do it regularly, it will most likely only be the once to be honest. I just want to extract the information so I can store it in a database for use at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what expect to get here - the file won't contain ratings. It may contain metadata such as comments. The comments on your question point to how to extract metadata - for which you may need to open the file - but you don't need to open the file to get the data you are currently capturing.